# addClass when click image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have image with 4 area clickable, when I click on one of the area will link to slide carousel bootstrap.

i am using this code for image map :

```
<img src="img/home-top.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" usemap="#map" />

<map name="map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="15,14,296,608" href="#" /> <!-- slide 1 active -->
  <area shape="rect" coords="334,17,623,613" href="#" /> <!-- slide 2 active -->
  <area shape="rect" coords="659,20,934,607" href="#" /> <!-- slide 3 active -->
  <area shape="rect" coords="978,18,1249,609" href="#" /> <!-- slide 4 active -->
</map>
```

and this code for slide carousel :

```
<div class="carousel-inner lg-size">
        <div id="slide-1" class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide-1.jpg');"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-2" class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide-2.jpg');"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-3" class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide-3.jpg');"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="slide-4" class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('img/slide-4.jpg');"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

this my code click function :

```
$("area").click(function(){
    $("#slide-1").addClass("active");
});
```

but it does not work to me.

[Check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/2093/)

Comment: Could you make a fiddle showing the problem? You aren't preventing default in your click event. So if you click the area and it got to the code it would add # to your url and you would probably notice that. So I imagine its not even getting into the click events. Also is that just test code to see if you ever get into the click event?

Comment: what is active class?

Comment: @ketan active class, will be the first slider..

Comment: @KevinF give me a few minutes to create on fiddle.

Comment: `$("area").click(function () {
    $('.carousel-inner .item.active').removeCass('active');
    $("#slide-" + ($(this).index() + 1)).addClass("active");
});`

Comment: @KevinF please check my fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
$("area").click(function()
{
   index= $(this).index(); //Get index position of current area tag
   ind = parseInt(index)+1; // .index function returns position from 0 so add 1 to current index
   $('.item').removeClass("active"); //Remove class active from slides
   $("#slide-"+ind).addClass("active"); //Add class active to corresponding slide
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, it seem work to me.:)  [work on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2TYv/2094/)

Comment: can i ask one more? How about, if i create two page. image map on home.html and slider carousel on index.html ? Thanks in advance

Comment: In that case, we can only redirect user to carousel page. We will need to write another script to add class, which will check the parameter in url and will add class to particular slide